# Me sale el siguiente error al ejecutar un api y usar el metodo get

Tags: sql, api, .net, rest

Estoy intentando ejecutar un `API` que estoy creando, al ejecutar el método get, me aparece el siguiente error

```
fail: Ecommerce.Application.Features.Products.Queries.GetProductList.GetProductListQuery[0]
      Application Request:Sucedio una excepcion para el request GetProductListQuery Ecommerce.Application.Features.Products.Queries.GetProductList.GetProductListQuery
      System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'Ecommerce.Infraestructure.Persistence.Repositories.RepositoryBase`1[Ecommerce.Domain.Product]'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.
         at System.RuntimeType.ActivatorCache..ctor(RuntimeType rt)
         at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)
         at Eccomerce.Infraestructure.Persistence.Repositories.UnitOfWork.Repository[TEntity]() in C:\Users\juanc\OneDrive\Desktop\amazonshop\backend\src\Infraestructure\Repositories\UnitOfWork.cs:line 48     
         at Ecommerce.Application.Features.Products.Queries.GetProductList.GetProductListQueryHandler.Handle(GetProductListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\juanc\OneDrive\Desktop\amazonshop\backend\src\Core\Ecommerce.Application\Features\Products\Queries\GetProductList\GetProductListQuerieHandler.cs:line 24
         at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Ecommerce.Application.Behaviors.ValidationBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\juanc\OneDrive\Desktop\amazonshop\backend\src\Core\Ecommerce.Application\Behaviors\ValidationBehavior.cs:line 28
         at Ecommerce.Application.Behaviors.UnhandledExceptionBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\juanc\OneDrive\Desktop\amazonshop\backend\src\Core\Ecommerce.Application\Behaviors\UnhandledExceptionBehaviour.cs:line 18
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Exception: Application Request Con Errores
         at Ecommerce.Application.Behaviors.UnhandledExceptionBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\juanc\OneDrive\Desktop\amazonshop\backend\src\Core\Ecommerce.Application\Behaviors\UnhandledExceptionBehaviour.cs:line 22
         at Ecommerce.Api.Controllers.ProductController.GetProductList() in C:\Users\juanc\OneDrive\Desktop\amazonshop\backend\src\api\Controllers\ProductController.cs:line 24
         at lambda_method38(Closure, Object)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822  3. ¿Cómo podemos reproducir tu escenario si tan solo nos das el stack trace del error? 4. En el mismo error, lee detenidamente, hay un fragmento clave: `RepositoryBase`1[Ecommerce.Domain.Product]'` y te detalla el motivo: `Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.`